# Prometheus: what's the difference between a Gauge and a GaugeMetricFamily?

Tags: prometheus

I understand that `Gauge` is for reporting e.g. application metrics "normally", and `GaugeMetricFamily` is for writing custom collectors and exporters. But I can't figure out how they meaningfully differ. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of it that `Gauge` is an instrumentation-friendly object the takes care of tracking values, concurrency, labels. At the end of this it produces a `GaugeMetricFamily` data structure as a snapshot of its current state (it doesn't actually use a `GaugeMetricFamily`, but that's an implementation detail) when needed by a scrape.

For custom collectors, you have to produce the `GaugeMetricFamily` yourself.